# syntax for including variable in php $_SERVER['variable']

Tags: php, syntax

i want to include a $profilepageuserid in the address, i am not sure about the proper syntax.

```
$page=$_SERVER['groups_page.php?view_profile_user_id=$profilepageuserid'];

header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
```

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do here?

Comment: Why are you accessing `$_SERVER`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of confusion here. What it appears you want to do is assign a URI to a page variable, and then issue this through the header function:

```
$page = "groups_page?view_profile_user_id=" .$profilepageuserid . ".php";
header( "Refresh: $sec; url: $page" );
```

I'm not sure why you're trying to access `$_SERVER` here, but the PHP interpreter will be confused as it appears you're calling a key within the array itself. Of course the `$_SERVER` array only has a finite number of keys, none of which resemble what you attempted to request: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
$page=$_SERVER['groups_page?view_profile_user_id=' . $profilepageuserid . '.php'];
```

Or:

```
$page=$_SERVER["groups_page?view_profile_user_id={$profilepageuserid}.php"];
```

You can only use variables in strings if they use double-quotes.  Otherwise, you have to break out the variable and concatenate it to the string.

Edit: not sure if the .php is in the correct spot, but you get the idea...